# There are some entries in the db that are out of date, please select

Tags: assets

EE 2.6.1
Assets 2.2.1

I was doing an index update in Assets when ran into that, someone can help me understand?

Comment: To start, I suggest upgrading to the most recent version of EE v 2.7 to rule issues between the older EE version and the newer Assets version.

Comment: Also, can you please provide more information in your question... Is the title of your question the error?? Are you seeing this every time you index?

Comment: Anna, this is not a real error but something strange I want to understand :-) and yes it's in the title! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing this message when updating Assets indexes, it means that there are some files or folders in the Assets index database, that reference files or folder that no longer exist physically on the server.

This could be due to deleting files via FTP or EE filemanager, for example.